# Syntax error when adding an array in the entity - Node.js, TypeORM, MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, typeorm

I'm using Node.js and TypeORM with MySQL but the error shows MariaDB I don't know why. I'm trying to use array in User entity and this must be the error

**ERROR**:

```
    QueryFailedError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
    code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
    errno: 1064,
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
    sqlState: '42000',
    index: 0,
    sql: 'ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `favorites` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '
  },
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'ALTER TABLE `user` ADD `favorites` text NOT NULL DEFAULT '
}
```

**The columns causing the error:**

```
  @Column({ type: "simple-array", default: [] })
  favorites: string[];

  @Column({ type: "simple-array", default: [] })
  cart: string[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have default value for column type `text` in mysql. Remove the `default` parameter in the column options and the query should work.

If you still want to have any default value set, you can write a native mysql trigger or use typeorm `@AfterInsert` hook to set the value of columns `cart` or `favorites` just after they're inserted in the database.

Comment: thanks! It worked when I just used the `@Column("simple-array")`